# Who is Saying "I love you too" in the end?

Tags: ending, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In the last episode of the 2nd season of Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles, "Born to Run", there was the last scene with electric sparking and we can hear a female voice, it's saying:

> I love you too...

So my question is who is this voice, is it Cameron's voice or another voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Wikia has the answer](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_222:_Born_to_Run):

> Q:' Did Sarah Connor actually go through the portal? If not, why did
>   Sarah Connor choose to leave her son behind, and **whose voice was the
>   one saying "I love you too, John" at the very end?**
>
> A: It is possible that Sarah jumped to the future after John and
>   Weaver. It is also possible that John Connor returned through the time
>   bubble at that point. He could have recovered the chip and returned to
>   the point in which he left days, weeks, months, even years later
>   without difficulty. **Most likely, her voice at the end was an artistic
>   touch added for closure. She was saying her goodbye to John.** Earlier
>   in the episode, John told Sarah he loved her — this could also be
>   Sarah letting go of John.